# Php - buscar foto em outra pasta do sistema

Tags: php

Boa tarde. Preciso buscar uma imagem que está em outra pasta de outro aplicativo dentro do mesmo diretório e agradeceria ajuda de como fazer:

Seria assim:

Meu arquivo escolha-produtos que está no diretório:

C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.19-0\apache2\htdocs\casamento\escolha-produtos.php

precisa ir buscar fotos de produtos que estão neste diretório:

C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.19-0\apache2\htdocs\cadastro\fotos

segue arquivo escolha-produtos onde faço a requisição da foto:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET["id"];
$produtos = listaProdutosporCategoria($conexao, $id);
?>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<?php foreach($produtos as $produto) : ?>

 <div class="section ">
  <div class="container container-border">


      <div class="title">
        <h4>Escolha os Produtos que Deseja Ganhar</h4>
           </div>
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="card card-product card-plain">
                    <div class="image">
                        <a href="#">
                            <img src="fotos/<?=$produto->getFoto() ?>"
  alt="Sem Imagem"/>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                        <a href="#">
                            <h4 class="title"><?=$produto->getNome() ?></h4>
                        </a>
                        <p class="description">
                          <?= substr($produto->getDescricao(), 0, 40) ?>
                        </p>
                        <div class="footer">
                            <span class="price">R$ <?=$produto->getPreco() ?
  ></span>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-simple btn-
 hover pull-right" rel="tooltip" title="" data-placement="left" data-
 original-title="Adicionar a lista">
                                <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- end card -->
            </div>


  </div>


  </div>

 </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

segue classe produto na função getFoto

```
public function getFoto()
{
return $this->foto;
}

public function carregaCaminhoFoto($foto)  {
    $this->foto = $foto;
}
```

segue banco-produto na função listaProdutosporCategoria:

```
function listaProdutosporCategoria($conexao,$id){
$produtos = array();
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, "select p.*, c.nome as categoria_nome,
m.nome as marca_nome 
from produtos p 
inner join categorias c on(p.categoria_id = c.id)
inner join marcas m on(p.marca_id = m.id) 
where c.id = {$id}");
while($array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {

$produto = new Produto();
$produto->setId($array['id']);
$produto->setNome($array['nome']);
$produto->setPreco($array['preco']);
$produto->setReferencia($array['referencia']);
$produto->setDescricao($array['descricao']);
$produto->setMarca(new Marca());
$produto->getMarca()->setId($array['marca_id']);
$produto->getmarca()->setNome($array['marca_nome']);
$produto->setCategoria(new Categoria());
$produto->getCategoria()->setId($array['categoria_id']);
$produto->getCategoria()->setNome($array['categoria_nome']);
$produto->carregaCaminhoFoto($array['foto']);

 array_push($produtos, $produto);
}
return $produtos;
 }
```

Comment: Tente assim: `$produto->carregaCaminhoFoto("../cadastro/fotos/" + $array['foto']);` ou `<img src="../cadastro/fotos/<?=$produto->getFoto() ?>"
  alt="Sem Imagem"/>`Não sei se as barras `/` estão certas, testes ai =)

Comment: Isso mesmo Gerep na segunda opção Valeu muito obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O caminho da imagem não está correto. Tente dessa forma:

`<img src="../cadastro/fotos/<?=$produto->getFoto() ?>" alt="Sem Imagem"/>`

Comment: Funcionou Jessica. !!!!! Perfeito !!! Muito obrigado